# need help solving stiff ode and finding the intersection point

Tags: equation-solving

Solve[{x, y} [Element]  InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}] && {x, y} [Element] Circle[], {x,  y}]

Comment: Duplicate of  [Need help solving stiff ODE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215163/need-help-solving-stiff-ode)

Comment: @Artes I am sorry. I need to delete that one and repost a new one. But I could not.

Comment: This should be done by the moderators, just flag it for further action.

Comment: @Artes thank...

Comment: @user69870 Please return to your old question, edit it and add substantially more details. After that, we can vote to reopen it. It was closed because it was impossible to run your example. Take your time, provide a good description and necessary code so that other users can understand what you try to achieve.